# Table title with outreg2

Tags: latex, stata

I am working with the *community-contributed* command `outreg2` to export regression estimates from a `logit` model to `LaTeX`.

Is there a way to show the table reference/label, for example, "Table 1: Some Title"?

I cannot seem to be able to do this using `outreg2`:

```
logit v1 v2 v43, or
outreg2 using "table", label cti(odds ratio) eform tex replace ctitle(Logit)
```

With `esttab`, using `\label` in the title option to get the desired result works:

```
esttab using "Table.tex",tex eform label replace title("Logit"\label{tab1})
```

Any suggestions?

---

**EDIT:**

Note that even when i do the following:

```
outreg2 using "table", label cti(odds ratio) eform tex replace ///
                       ctitle(Logit) title("Logit"\label{tab1})
```

This only produces the following:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following toy example:

```
webuse lbw
logit low age lwt i.race smoke ptl ht ui, or
```

Both `esttab` and `outreg2` produce the same result when their `title()` option is used:

```
esttab, tex eform label replace title("Logit"\label{tab1})

outreg2 using "table", tex label cti(odds ratio) eform replace title("Logit"\label{tab1})
```

However, this will not work when typesetting as `outreg2` produces
different markup than `esttab`.

The way to do what you want with `outreg2` is to run the following from Stata:

```
outreg2 using table, tex replace label cti(odds ratio) eform
```

Unlike `esttab`, the `outreg2` command does not have an option to insert markup
directly from within Stata. Thus you will have to add the markup below manually:

```
.
.
.
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{Logit \label{tab1}}
.
.
.
\end{table}
.
.
.
```

The produced `tex` file should then look as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{Logit \label{tab1}}
\begin{tabular}{lc} \hline
 & (1) \\
VARIABLES & odds ratio \\ \hline
 &  \\
birthweight<2500g &  \\
 &  \\
age of mother & 0.973 \\
 & (0.0355) \\
weight at last menstrual period & 0.985** \\
 & (0.00682) \\
race = 2, black & 3.535** \\
 & (1.861) \\
race = 3, other & 2.368** \\
 & (1.040) \\
smoked during pregnancy & 2.518** \\
 & (1.009) \\
premature labor history (count) & 1.719 \\
 & (0.595) \\
has history of hypertension & 6.250*** \\
 & (4.322) \\
presence, uterine irritability & 2.135* \\
 & (0.981) \\
Constant & 1.586 \\
 & (1.910) \\
 &  \\
 Observations & 189 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ seEform in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here for future reference.

Actually, if you add the option *tex(fragment)* to *outreg2*, the resulting file will only contain the *tabular* environment. Then, you can create the *table* environment, with the caption that you desire, and use *\input* only to replace the *tabular* environment.